# Android device monitor using different java version from JAVA_HOME and Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8, android-monitor

I've got Android Studio 3.0 The settings in the Project Structure - JDK location - `"C:\Java\jdk1.8"` and there is my 1.8 jdk. But on this PC the JAVA_HOME variable is set to `"C:\Java\jdk1.7"`.

Then then I can't open the Android device monitor. I am receiving a log file saying:

```
java.version=1.7.0_80
....
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorPlugin for bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor is invalid
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Without changing the JAVA_HOME how can I run Android Studio with jdk1.8?

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Windows 10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally solved this. I started by setting JAVA_HOME to point jdk1.8, then I set Project Structure - JDK location to point jdk1.8 too, and also I modified the .bat file that starts the Android Studio to set Java version 1.8. But none of this helped. My Android device monitor was still saying that I am using jdk1.7. So after a little research, I found that actually, it is not part of Android Studio, it is a standalone tool as part of the Android SDK:

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html

So I started looking at how to set java on that stand-alone tool and I what I did was to go to its location `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64`. There I found the **monitor.ini** which I believe is responsible for the initialization of the Android device monitor so I just added the java version I want to use and it worked. See screenshot :

[image]